# PHP Active record - how to add not in condition in all() function

Tags: phpactiverecord

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem in using the **not in** condition in the following code:

```
$filter=implode(',',array(1,2));

$list = static::all(array('conditions' => array('org_grp_id = ? AND org_active = ? and     org_id not in (?)', $group, 1,$filter), 'order' => 'org_name'));

return $list;
```

For information, this **all()** function is from **php ActiveRecord** class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass values for `IN (?)` as an array, not as a string.

Try this:

```
$filter = array(1, 2);
```